# Graphing complex vectors

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors, graphing-functions

I have the complex vector

$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i\\-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i\end{bmatrix}$$

and I'm not sure how to graph it because on the complex plane you graph complex numbers with the real vs the imaginary axis, but in this case there are complex numbers for the $x$ and $y$ - please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Since $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$ we would have $\mathbb{C}^2 \cong \mathbb{R}^4$ which is impossible to graph directly.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek, so we can't graph it?

Comment: No, not really. You can write the vector as a sum of two real vectors, and plot the real and imaginary part separately, that would be an option.